# OpenAI ChatGPT (GPT-3.5) API error 400: "'user' is not of type 'object'"

Tags: r, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I share with you my code bellow to get a response from a POST request with R from OPENAI chatgpt api :

```
param <- list(model = "gpt-3.5-turbo",
              messages = c("role" = "user", 
                           "content" = "Hello"))

result <- POST("https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions",
               body = param,
               add_headers(Authorization=openai_secret_key),
               encode = "json")
```

Here is the result :

> Response [https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions]
> Date: 2023-03-02 16:28
> Status: 400
> Content-Type: application/json
> Size: 158 B
> {
> “error”: {
> “message”: “‘user’ is not of type ‘object’ - ‘messages.0’”,
> “type”: “invalid_request_error”,
> “param”: null,
> “code”: null
> }
> }

So the user and the content part is not working but the model is working

Thanks a lot

In postman, I have this JSON working but can't make it work in R

```
{
   "model":"gpt-3.5-turbo",
   "messages":[
      {
         "role":"user",
         "content":"Hello!"
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run `test.r` the OpenAI API will return the following completion:

> [1] "\n\nHello! How may I assist you today?"

**test.r**

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)

OPENAI_API_KEY <- "sk-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

param <- list(model = "gpt-3.5-turbo",
              messages = list(list(role = "user", content = "Hello"))
         )
    
result <- POST("https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions",
               body = param,
               add_headers("Authorization" = paste("Bearer", OPENAI_API_KEY)),
               encode = "json")

response_content <- fromJSON(rawToChar(result$content))
print(response_content$choices[[1]]$content)
```

Comment: I have added toJSON to convert the list to json but still doesn't work

Comment: I tried it, now the model parameter is not recognized "message": "you must provide a model parameter", I have edited my question

Comment: I edited my answer once again. What about now?

Comment: I have the follow error : Error in force(x) : argument "x" is missing, with no default

Comment: See **EDIT 3**. What about now?

Comment: Still doesn't work. "message": "you must provide a model parameter"

Comment: I have updated my question with the code that works with your help, could you please update yours so I can accept it as an answer. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: I edited my answer. Can you please check if this is okay? You're welcome. :)